# How can I get my display to show GO code with FYNE gui?

Tags: go, fyne

I am building a simple GUI, and found a built in one for use with my GOLANG code. I have tried to simply run a go run main.go with the example of their hello world just to test functionality. Got an issue that there was no DISPLAY variable. Then set the variable and now I'm getting this issue.  Please assist!

```golang
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Hello World")

    w.SetContent(widget.NewLabel("Hello World!"))
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Error is shown here [image: ERROR]

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of work, days of being completely frustrated. I found the answer. starting with setting the correct display in conjunction with your ipaddress.

export DISPLAY=(your IP address):0.0  the :0.0 sets to your default display.

You want to then follow this information:

setting your first inbound rule
[image]

set 3 of these as listed here
[image: vcxserv inbound]

name them however you would like. Just ensure you have set TCP and UDP and an ALL category under the protocol. Mine only worked when setting all 3, (when I figured setting just 1 with all category would work for the protocol.)

Comment: The IP should only be needed if you are displaying on a remote computer. DISPLAY is set automatically when X is running locally, unless you’re doing something strange with users or access control…?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `fyne.io/fyne/v2` in our code like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"  // add this line to your code
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Hello World")

    w.SetContent(widget.NewLabel("Hello World!"))
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running Linux with a Wayland setup. Not all apps support this yet, so it is recommended to switch on “xwayland” which adds X11 compatibility.

Fyne is working on wayland support and you can try it out using the “-tags wayland” build parameter. It is about 95% complete, we aim to have it enabled by default later this year.

Comment: This is using bash on VS code. Should I do anything differently?

Comment: It is the setup of your computer not your dev environment that is a challenge. As above I’d recommend enabling XWayland. How to do that is Platform specific but your distribution will have docs.